# Question about a notation. Norm of the derivative of a function at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given is an analytic function from $M$ to $N$, both equipped with conformal Riemannian metric, say $g$ and $h$ resp.

What might the $h$ norm of the derivative of the function at a point mean?

$\|f'(x)\| $ with respect to the $h$ metric.

Thanks

ADD:

It was used in this context:

d(x,y) < d(f(x),f(y)), both defined by the same metric, x,y,f(x),f(y) are in the same space. And the conclusion is that f is expanding, or $\|f'(x)\| $ > 1 with respect to this metric

Comment: $f'(x)$ is a linear map from one normed space to another. Surely, its norm must be the operator norm? But you could also use the Hilbert–Schmidt norm, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for response, but in the paper I read, it did not talk about operator norm D:

Answer (score 2):

The context given makes it clear they are talking about the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). In this context, this can be defined as
$$ \|f'(x)\|=\sup\sqrt{\frac{h(f'(x)u,f'(x)u)}{g(u,u)}}, $$
the supremum taken over all nonzero tangent vectors $u$ at $x$.