# How can I calculate the derivative of $\| \mathrm{d}f \|^2_h$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

The present question refers to one of the answers of this [other one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845525/question-about-a-notation-norm-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-at-a-point/846580#846580)

Let $h=h_{ij}dx^i \otimes dx^j$ be a Riemannian metric.

(1) Why does the inverse $(h_{ij})^{-1}=h^{ij}$ appear here:
$$\| \mathrm{d}f \|^2_h = h^{-1}(\mathrm{d}f ,\mathrm{d}f) = f_{x_i}f_{x_j}h^{ij}=\langle \nabla f , \nabla f \rangle_h ?$$

(2) Putting $f(x,t) = f(x) + t g(x)$, how can I calculate $\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0} \| \mathrm{d}f \|^2_h$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) is just definition. For (2), what did you try?

Comment: (1) Why not $h(df,df)$?, (2) $\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0} \| \mathrm{d}f \|^2_h = 2\langle df, dg \rangle_h$, but I wonder if $h^{ij}$ shouldn't play a role in it...

Comment: Are you assuming that $f : M\to \mathbb R$ or $f: M \to N$?

Comment: I'm assuming $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions on M, $f,g:M \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (1) You can't define $h$ on the cotangent space. (2) you are correct. $h$ depends only on $x$ and not on $f$.